# How to add css in themes default.xml blocks?

Tags: magento-2.1

```
<referenceContainer name="header.container">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test" before="-" template="Magento_Theme::html/header1.phtml">
               <arguments>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header</argument>
                </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="top.links">
                </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your custom css file at

> app/design/fronted/vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/web/css/custom.css

Now add your **custom.css** in the head tag of your theme's **default.xml** file as below

> app/design/fronted/vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <head>
    <css src="css/custom.css" />
  </head>
</page>
```

Run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`